# Why we do we use DS to call procedures?

Tags: assembly, x86, reverse-engineering

While reversing we see some intermodular call like `call dword ds:[004000238h]` or `call dword  ptr ds:_imp_atoi`.
Why it using the data segment instead of using the code segment (`CS`)?

Answer (score 1):

`call dword ds:[004000238h]` is an *indirect near call*, it read the value of the DWORD at *004000238h* and uses it to make the call.

Note that the square brackets and the `dword ptr` are a spot on for determining the type of the instruction.

Since the operand of the instruction is a memory operand, `DS` is implicitly being used to read it (with the disassembler being pedantic in showing it with the segment override syntax).

The call is near (far calls in protected mode are rare and carry a special semantic) so the current value of `CS` is not changed.
We can say that `CS` is implicitly used as the call is relative to the current value of `CS`.

[Intel manual 3](https://www-ssl.intel.com/content/www/us/en/architecture-and-technology/64-ia-32-architectures-software-developer-system-programming-manual-325384.html) describes the calling mechanisms in [protected mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protected_mode).

As a side note, even for 32-bit systems the segmentation is effectively disabled (all descriptors have base zero), so you can forget about selector registers but for TLS and SEH (that usually make use of the `fs`/`gs` registers).

Comment: why do we need Import address table even in static linking modules in c.  I  think IAT used in dynamically linking

Comment: @user7445340 It's hard to say without a specific example but Windows APIs are implemented mostly as user space DLLs. The C runtime still needs to load libraries like `user32` and `kernel32`.